# How to send text to the elements for creating an account on Facebook through Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/rootlente/Desktop/Driver For Selenium Chrome/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver")
driver.get("http://facebook.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("firstname").send_keys("Ilia")
driver.find_element_by_name("lastname").send_keys("james")
driver.find_element_by_name("reg_email__").send_keys("mail@mail.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("reg_email_confirmation__").send_keys("mail@mail.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("reg_passwd__").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='"sex"']")["2"].click()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: thank you a lot man! i was trying to add gender choice button all day

Comment: Why would you need to create Facebook accounts using Selenium? That can not possible have any non-spammer application.

Comment: it is kind of project for user security awareness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I inspect the page, it's `name="sex"` and the `value` is `"2"` for Male. You have `value="sex"`

change:

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='"sex"']")["2"].click()`

**to Select Male:**

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='sex'][value='2']").click()
```

or

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='sex']")[1].click()
```

**to select Female:**

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='sex'][value='1']").click()`

or

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='sex']")[0].click()`

EDIT: I like Andersson's comment below and his code is a tad better than my line (in my opinion), so I added it. So gives you options

Comment: Also if OP wants to select *second* element matched by CSS selector, then proper code line is `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][name='sex']")[1].click()`

Answer (score 0):

To send *character sequence* to the elements for creating an account on *Facebook* homepage you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.inputtext[name='firstname']"))).send_keys("Ilia")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.inputtext[name='lastname']").send_keys("james")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.inputtext[name='reg_email__']").send_keys("mail@mail.com") 
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.inputtext[name='reg_email_confirmation__']").send_keys("mail@mail.com") 
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.inputtext[name='reg_passwd__']").send_keys("password")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(@for, 'u_0_') and text()='Male']//preceding::input[1]").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot

[image: facebook_registration]